# Maven Spring (4.1.1 release) issue while starting tomcat

Tags: spring, maven

I am building my project using java 8 and spring 4.x  and Maven 4.

I used below commands to build and run the project :

```
mvn clean install
mvn tomcat:run
```

I am trying to run the project on windows 8 platform.
    I am getting below error while trying to start tomcat after building project with maven 4 :

```
Jul 27, 2018 3:07:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2018-07-27 15:07:40 [main] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/ResolvableTypeProvider

Jul 27, 2018 3:07:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jul 27, 2018 3:07:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/CounterWebApp] startup failed due to previous errors
Jul 27, 2018 3:07:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

My pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mkyong</groupId>
    <artifactId>CounterWebApp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>CounterWebApp Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <jcl-over-slf4j.version>1.7.5</jcl-over-slf4j.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Unit Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${jcl-over-slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>CounterWebApp</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Eclipse project -->
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                    <!-- Always download and attach dependencies source code -->
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                <!-- Avoid type mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0 -->
                <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <!-- Set JDK Compiler Level -->
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <!-- For Maven Tomcat Plugin -->
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>/CounterWebApp</path>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I did some investigation and I think there might be issues with spring versions but I have checked my maven and it has spring 4.1.1 dependency only.

Comment: There are two things wrong... Maven does not have Spring ...and Maven 4 doest not exist...furthermore the question is: Why are you using such an old Spring version ? Apart from that remove maven-eclipse-plugin cause it's retired for a long time...better use M2E support in Eclipse...

Comment: Sorry my bad it' maven apache-maven-3.5.4.I have added spring dependency in pom.xml. What do you mean by "Maven does not have Spring" ?

Comment: You wrote: `but I have checked my maven and it has spring 4.1.1 dependency only..`. Maven has not spring dependency. You have written in your pom file to use spring dependencies....it a little bit confusing...

Comment: Really sorry if it confused you. I am trying from command line but getting error. I guess it's because of below dependency :            <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

Your problem related with Spring version.Use Spring 3.2.0

Comment: Hi Mustafa                                                                                                                Thanks for the reply. Why do use older version of Spring ?

Comment: Hi, excatly I don't know :) But this versions maybe don't stabil for each other.

Comment: Thanks. Will try that and let you now.